# How would I prove that the limit of $f(x) = 1/(x^2 - 1) = - 1$ as $x \to 0$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Tags: calculus

So far all that I have is that we require $|\frac{x^2}{x^2 - 1} |< \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$

I'm having difficulty choosing $\delta$ that works. The textbook that we're following in class doesn't have any kind of solved example on a similar problem so I'm completely lost here. Please help.

Comment: Can you explain why f(x) in the title is different form the f(x) given in the text?

Comment: @Vinod The formula to be bound, given in the text is the result of adding 1 to the f(x) of the title, since the limit is to be shown to be -1.

Answer (score 1):

First stipulate that $\delta < 1/2.$ That done, the absolute value of $1/(x^2-1)$ will be bounded above by $4/3$ so that also the absolute value of $x^2/(1-x^2)$ will be bounded above by $(4/3)x^2.$ Putting this less than $\epsilon$ then gives $|x|<\sqrt{(3/4)\epsilon}.$ This all means your $\delta$ can be defined as
$$\delta = \min(1/2, \sqrt{(3/4)\epsilon}).$$

The use of the min here is because we want *both* $\delta<1/2$ (to make the upper bound $4/3$ at that point), *and* $\delta$ small enough to make $|x|$ at most $\sqrt{(3/4)\epsilon.}$

Comment: Is there a reason you're choosing $\delta < 1/2$? Does it always work? If not, how would you know what $\delta$ to choose?

Comment: The reason for $\delta=1/2$ at the start is somewhat arbitrary, it just needs at that stage to be small enough that the magnitude of the denominator $x^2-1$ is bounded below by a strictly positive constant.  (to make it avoid being near zero) When $x=1/2$  this magnitude is $3/4$ which is why the $4/3$ shows up in one of the bounds.

Comment: @Acid2 Just another response, since the last one didn't include your username, this one means you'll get notified...